# Write a result of a function in a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to write the result of a function in a csv. Unfortunately, no pandas.

**csv file input:**

```
Hello all well?
today is cold!
I have not had lunch yet
He does not have many brothers or sisters.
We are sick
```

**Script:**

```
import re
import csv
import string

with open('teste_csv.csv', 'r') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f)

    for line in file:
        message = ''.join(line)

        def toto(message):

            message = message.lower()

            p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, string.punctuation)))
            no_punct = p.sub(' ', message)

            writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'w'))
            for row in no_punct:
                writer.writerow(row)

                return writer

         print(toto(message))
```

At my terminal, I have <_csv.writer object at 0x7fee60e57c50> and in my result.csv I have only one line written 'w'. I would like each line to be in my result.csv

Comment: Just separate this to three fucntions that read, process and write back to file, and a little puppy will not die when you run that code.

Comment: This is not a csv file. Why do you want to use the csv module on that???

Comment: I agree with you, but I have no other choice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep erasing the file since everytime you call `toto` it opens `result.csv` for writing, hence you are left only with a single write. You need to open the file once ,and create the wirter once. You also only need to define the function once for that matter:

```
import re
import csv
import string

def toto(message,writer):
    message = message.lower()
    p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, string.punctuation)))
    no_punct = p.sub(' ', message)
    for row in no_punct:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('teste_csv.csv', 'r') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv','w'))
    file = csv.reader(f)
    for line in file:
        message = ''.join(line)
        toto(message,writer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the writer outside of your first loop. each time you are looping throw it's opening and rewriting the file

another issue you are defining and calling the toto inside the loop so it's getting called with last message value.

```
import re
import csv
import string

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'w'))
    def toto(message):

        message = message.lower()
        p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, string.punctuation)))
        no_punct = p.sub(' ', message)
        for row in no_punct:
            writer.writerow(row)
            return writer     
    for line in file:
        print line
        message=''.join(line)

    print(toto(message))
```